# Expanding list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, expandable

I am looking for a way to optimize the current code that I have:

```
        for result in results:
            if result != '':
                if isinstance(result, list):
                    for subresult in result:
                        if subresult != '':
                            worksheet.write(r, c, subresult)
                            c += 1
                else:
                    worksheet.write(r, c, result)
                    c += 1
```

I also use this in a particular case:

```
        for result in results:
            if isinstance(result, list):
                for subresult in result:
                    worksheet.write(r, c, subresult)
                    c += 1
            else:
                worksheet.write(r, c, result)
                c += 1
```

I have a list that in some instances contains only a single value, while in other instances it contains multiple values (i.e. another list).

Here is an example of what the list may contain:

```
results = ['', '', '', '390', '66', ['Name', 'SerialNumber', 'Model', 'Year'], 'SW_Version', ['HD_Loc', 'HD_Model', 'HD_FW', 'HD_SerialNumber', 'Man_Yr', 'Man_Mth'], '', '', '']
```

Ultimately I want to be able to output each value to its own column in excel. In some cases I only want to output the parts of the list that contain a value, which is performed by the first snippet of code I provided. In other cases I want to output all parts of the list, regardless of whether it has a value or not, which is performed by the second snippet of code I provided.

I have seen instances where a `for` loop and some action statement, lets say `print`, have been combined into a single line of python code, but I have been unable to get that syntax to work with the snippets that I have provided.

This code is currently working in the way I have implemented it, I am just looking for a way to shorten/optimize it as the program I have it inside of is starting to get fairly large and being able to shorten this would help me in shortening other parts of the program also.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** In both cases the order of which it is output does matter, and I would like to have it output in the order that it is currently in (just minus the `''` in the one scenario).

Comment: so do you want to convert a list of lists to simply a list?

Comment: Effectively yes. When I perform the above code I get `['', '', '', '390', '66', 'Name', 'SerialNumber', 'Model', 'Year', 'SW_Version', 'HD_Loc', 'HD_Model', 'HD_FW', 'HD_SerialNumber', 'Man_Yr', 'Man_Mth', '', '', '']` and that is what I want output to my excel file (each being in their own cell.)

Comment: look at this link and the links in the OP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python?rq=1

Comment: Jeremy, I had tried that but I receive this: `['3', '9', '0', '6', '6', 'Name', 'SerialNumber', 'Model', 'Year', 'S', 'W', '_', 'V', 'e', 'r', 's', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'HD_Loc', 'HD_Model', 'HD_FW', 'HD_SerialNumber', 'Man_Yr', 'Man_Mth']` Looks like anything that was not in a list inside the list gets separated out by character, but anything that was in a list is fine.

Comment: I posted a tentative solution. I will try and clean it up a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps,

```
results = ['', '', '', '390', '66', ['Name', 'SerialNumber', 'Model', 'Year'], 'SW_Version', ['HD_Loc', 'HD_Model', 'HD_FW', 'HD_SerialNumber', 'Man_Yr', 'Man_Mth'], '', '', '']

flatList = [item for sublist in [[item] if not isinstance(item,list) else item for item in results] for item in sublist]

flatListWithoutBlanks = [item for item in [item for sublist in [[item] if not isinstance(item,list) else item for item in results] for item in sublist] if item != '' ]
```

best,

Comment: Thanks, this does work for the second snippet of code I provided where I want to output the blanks, `''`, but is there a way to make it work for the first snippet where I want to exclude the blanks `''`?

Comment: I have upvoted it, but does not currently show since I do not have enough reputation :(. Still a StackOverflow noob.

Comment: No problem.. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this neatly with recursion:

```
def worksheet_writer(results):
        if isinstance(results, list):
                for item in results: worksheet_writer(item)
        else:
                worksheet.write(r, c, results)
                c += 1
```

Edited to support strings.

Comment: jpcgt, I tried this and recieved" `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<tmp 2>", line 11, in <module>
    worksheet_writer(results)
  File "<tmp 2>", line 3, in worksheet_writer
    for item in results: worksheet_writer(item)...(repeates for awhile)...
  File "<tmp 2>", line 3, in worksheet_writer
    for item in results: worksheet_writer(item)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: This will cause a stack overflow on a string, because iterating over a string yields strings.

Comment: @RC_Crusher07: I just modified the answer to support string. Still, same recursion technique.

Comment: @jpcgt: This works for the second snippet of code I had added, but for the first piece where I want to exclude the blanks `''`, where would be the best place to add in `item != ''`?

Comment: @RC_Crusher07: Instead of `else:` do `elif results != '':`. Not lines added!

Comment: @jpcgt: Thanks, that did it. But SuJaY posted closer to what I was looking for with the one liner that could do it, I have upvoted yours though.

Comment: @RC_Crusher07: Appreciated. But you wanted better code, which can be either more readable, maintainable or faster. That one-liner is certainly not as readable, maintainable or faster.

Comment: @jpcgt: I am still fairly new to python. Is there an easy way I would be able to test the performance of your code versus the one a did choose to see if there is an advantage to one over the other?

Comment: @RC_Crusher: One basic rule in software development is NEVER optimize for speed at the cost of readability and maintainability unless it's absolutely necessary. For measuring speed see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script

Answer (score 1):

Okay here's the solution I've got so far. It's a kinda messy list comprehension. I'll try and clean it up a bit.

```
results = ['', '', '', '390', '66', ['Name', 'SerialNumber', 'Model', 'Year'], 'SW_Version', ['HD_Loc', 'HD_Model', 'HD_FW', 'HD_SerialNumber', 'Man_Yr', 'Man_Mth'], '', '', '']
li = list(set([item if type(sublist) is list else sublist for sublist in results for item in sublist]))
print li
```

This gives an output of:

```
['SW_Version', 'Name', 'HD_FW', 'SerialNumber', 'HD_Model', 'HD_SerialNumber', '390', '66', 'Year', 'Model', 'Man_Yr', 'HD_Loc', 'Man_Mth']
```

Comment: This does work, but it moves the values in the list out of order. Sorry I forgot to mention that order does matter, I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

I posted it in a comment but not sure if it will be clear so ,

```
flatListWithoutBlanks = [item for item in [item for sublist in [[item] if not isinstance(item,list) else item for item in results] for item in sublist] if item != '' ]
```